# Supplement book for topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I am taking a course in topology with Gamelin and Greene, Introduction to topology. I would like to have some supplement to extend and give more motivation and explanation. I am quite tired of the "theorem, proof, theorem, proof" pattern.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm putting in a vote for the "Schaum's Outline" volume on "General Topology" by Lipschutz.  It's lightweight and full of detailed explanations, with problems and their solutions. It's also under $20, so if you don't like it you haven't wasted a lot of money.

Comment: @MJD thank you very much! I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 5):

My recommendation is to not restrict your search to a single book for a supplement, but rather assemble several similar books and use all of them. Something in one book might not make sense, then you read about the same topic in another book and you understand the topic, and then, amazingly, when you look back at the first book again you find that the treatment of the topic in the first book gives, for you, the better treatment --- you simply needed some mental nudging from the second book in order to “read what had originally been a Foreign language to you” in the first book. Of course, for someone else, both books might be opaque on the topic, and a third book will work for that person. Most often, however, is that you pick up some understanding on the topic from each of several books, and when you assemble together what all the books say on that topic, then you mostly understand it. (Note: To go from “mostly understand it” to “understand it very well”, find someone in your class who doesn’t understand it and explain it to them! Or search Mathematics Stack Exchange for a question on the topic and write an answer that broadly explains the topic.)

In today’s world, in which students rarely check out university library books, there should be plenty of appropriate topology books sitting on the library shelves --- look for such books around the QA 611 location, if your library uses the U.S. Library of Congress classification. Things were quite different when I was in college, by the way. Then, whenever a topology class was being offered, most of the better known undergraduate and beginning graduate level texts would be snapped off the shelves within the first few days of class, and similarly for other classes in advanced specific areas.

I just looked at my copy of Gamelin/Green (1999 2nd edition) to get an idea of its level. Below are some books that seem to fit the best (i.e. I’m skipping Kelly, Dugundji, Wilansky, Gaal, Cullen, Munkres, Engelking, Willard, Thron, Schubert, Pervin, etc. level books), at least for the first two chapters. (Chapters 3 and 4 of Gamelin/Green deal with homotopy theory.) The first 5 books are from my bookshelves, the next 4 books I know about but don’t actually have in front of me right now, and the 4 remaining books are those I found by looking at the amazon.com suggestions. There are likely many more books that could be useful that your library might have, because books mentioned by people online are typically rather recent (or recently have been reprinted by Dover Publications), and many older gems will be overlooked if you only rely on superficial online searches. A non-superficial search would be to look at the bibliographies of all the books you can get a hold of, but since you probably have very limited financial funds, this won’t do much good unless the books you find out about are actually in the library, so this is another reason to look there --- everything you see will definitely be something you can make use of for free.

[**Undergraduate Topology. A Working Textbook**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198702345) by Aisling McCluskey and Brian McMaster (2014)

[**Undergraduate Topology**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486474194) by Robert H. Kasriel (1971/2009)

> For what it’s worth, this is the book I used for my first topology course (an independent reading course), and [this 28 March 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sci.math/qYuDHb-_Vcs/40zrZodLffMJ) gives some of my thoughts on the book.

[**Fundamentals of Topology**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0024106402) by Benjamin T. Sims (1976)

[**Schaums Outline of General Topology**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071763473) by Seymour Lipschutz (1965)

[**Introduction to Topology**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486663523) by Bert Mendelson (1975/1990 3rd edition)

[**Topology**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387908927) by K. Jänich (1984)

[**Theory and Examples of Point-Set Topology**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0818549750) by John Greever (1967)

[**Principles of Topology**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486801543) by Fred H. Croom (1989/2016)

[**Introduction to Topology**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1575240084) by Crump W. Baker (1991)

[**An Illustrated Introduction to Topology and Homotopy**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1439848157) by Sasho Kalajdzievski (2015) [see [Solutions Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1138553468) also]

[**Understanding Topology: A Practical Introduction**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/142142407X) by Shaun V. Ault (2018)

[**Introduction to Topology. Pure and Applied**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131848690) by Colin Adams and Robert Franzosa (2007)

[**Elementary Point-Set Topology**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/048680349X) by Andre L. Yandl and Adam Bowers (2016)

Comment: Wow! thank you for the comment! Actually I am doing like that, but the books I am also using are not helping too much(simmons and Willard), and apparently our library doesn't have a large collection of general topology books. The first three books do are not there, and all the books start from Greever and downward are not there. Question: why did you skip Kelly, Dugundji and so on?

Comment: I skipped those books because I assumed they were too advanced. My impression was that you were taking/studying an undergraduate level (by U.S. standards) topology course, so I omitted anything at roughly the Kelly level and above. If you want books that are more advanced, google my name as a phrase "Dave L Renfro" along with "topology" or "general topology" or "Engelking" etc. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2254363/definitions-of-a-topological-space-reference/2254849#2254849), for example.

Comment: If you could buy only one of the books, what would you invest on? or what would you think is most suitable as a textbook.

Comment: What I would be most interested in, even 40+ years ago when I was learning the material, is probably not what would be most suitable for you, and not knowing anything about you, I have no idea what would work best for you. Your current book has a fair amount of homotopy theory in it ("fair amount", because one of the four chapters in the book deals with higher homotopy groups), and some of the books above (but not all) include some homotopy theory. Having some homotopy theory in a supplementary reference would not be important to me, but it might be important to you.

Comment: My course only covers the first 7 sections in chapter 1 and the second chapter in Gamelin and Greene book, so I would not need more than that. I have had 5 courses in calculus, analysis and ODE, and also two courses in abstract algebra. (Math major)

Comment: Maybe [**Topology Without Tears**](http://www.topologywithouttears.net/topbook.pdf) (freely available), the book by Croom, and the book by Yandl/Bowers. Maybe also the book by Mendelson if you have enough $ after buying the other two.

Answer (score 1):

Munkres-Topology book is a nice book. It gives good intiution I think. I haven't studied various topology book so Munkers is only one I can recommend but anyone studied Munkres likes it

Comment: I studied Munkres and didn't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Paul Alexandroff's *Elementary Concepts of Topology* may be what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these books:
A first course in topology: Continuity and dimension by John McCleary.
Basic Topology : M.A Armstrong