# Motivated Reading on Topology?

Tags: general-topology

I am looking for a book on Topology which isn't solely focused on cramming theorems and proofs down the reader's throat: I have already read a significant chunk of Munkres. What I am looking for now is a textbook which can truly cement intuition behind all the basic concepts of the course. If anybody has any recommendations, I would appreciate it. Thank you! (And Happy Holidays!)

(For further context, I will be taking a graduate-level course on Algebraic Topology during Spring. My background in Topology is confined almost entirely to the readings of Munkres over the past week, alongside a brief discussion relating measurable and topological spaces in Real Analysis.)

---

To provide an example as to what exactly I'm looking for: Paul Halmos' *Naive Set Theory*. This textbook served a strong role in motivating and therefore teaching the basics to all things Set Theory.

Another example: Folland's *Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications* in comparison with Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*. While I do appreciate the brevity and to-the-point nature of Folland, it can be extraordinarily confusing to a first-time learner: The motivation is lacking, and definitions are sometimes left to the reader to assume understood. Rudin's textbook provides a far more motivated approach to the material, using a direct connection between the study of continuous (and later, Riemann integrable) functions to measurable (and later, Lebesgue integrable) functions. The theory suddenly becomes far more intuitive.

Comment: If you know real and complex analysis then you can find, in that subject itself, much of the intuition of general topology: open and closed subsets and their properties; limit points of subsets; interior points of subsets; closures of subsets; interiors of subsets; the definition of continuous functions; ... When reading Munkres, match those topics as they are introduced back with the versions you learned in analysis.

Comment: But perhaps this answers your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4411944/textbook-for-first-course-in-point-set-topology?rq=1

Comment: Jänich provides lots of intuition.

Comment: Or this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2771955/supplement-book-for-topology/2772097#2772097

Comment: For a more geometric oriented overview, [**Elementary Topology**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0138638799) by Dennis Martin Roseman (1999). For a more analysis oriented overview, [**Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis**](https://maa.org/press/maa-reviews/introduction-to-topology-and-modern-analysis) by George Finlay Simmons (1963/2003). Given that you'll be taking algebraic topology soon, I recommend Roseman over Simmons. You might also want to look at [**Algebraic Topology: An Introduction**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387902716) by William Schumacher Massey (1967/1977).

Comment: I was thinking about your question again and it occurred to me that instead of what you asked for, it might be better to focus on the topic of quotient spaces -- read and work through its treatment in **several texts**. Restricting yourself to quotient space sections of topology texts is a more realistic task for the next few weeks, and this topic will be especially relevant for your algebraic topology course -- see [Hatcher Algebraic Topology: I have all the prereqs, so why is this book unreadable for me?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3492949/13130).

Comment: Thank you all for your responses! @DaveL.Renfro I will certainly look into the Hatcher Algebraic Topology textbook (I just realized, as I was typing, that's in fact the textbook which'll be used in my course next semester). This should certainly all be very useful.

Comment: While looking for something else, I came across [*Notes on Introductory Point-Set Topology*](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Top/TopNotes.pdf) (also [at archive.org](https://archive.org/details/X8QX889XQ8HXQ89XH9HX8SSIQO/Notes%20on%20Introductory%20Point-Set%20Topology%20%20-%20Allen%20Hatcher/)) by Allen Hatcher (author of your upcoming algebraic topology text). [Description of the notes](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Top/Topdownloads.html) -- Hatcher says they form the first part of a topology course he taught in 2005.