# Theorem 5.12 in Schaum's _General Topology_: Topologies characterised by Kuratowski Closure Axioms

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

How to rigorously prove the following result?

> Let $X$ be a non-empty set and let $k \colon \mathscr{P}(X) \longrightarrow \mathscr{P}(X)$ satisfy the following Kuratowski Closure Axioms:

> [K$_1$] $k(\emptyset) = \emptyset$,
> [K$_2$] $A \subset k(A)$,
> [K$_3$] $k( A \cup B) = k(A) \cup k(B)$,
> [K$_4$] $k\big( k(A) \big) = k(A)$.

> Then there exists one and only one topology $\mathscr{T}$ on $X$ such that $k(A)$ will be the $\mathscr{T}$-closure of $A \subset X$.

From the above four axioms, we can also prove the following:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be any subsets of $X$ such that $A \subset B$. Then $k(A) \subset k(B)$ also.

Proof:

> As $A \subset B$, so we have $B = A \cup (B \setminus A)$, and hence
> \begin{align}
> k(B) &= k \big( A \cup (B \setminus A) \big) \\
> &= k(A) \cup k(B \setminus A) \\
> &\supset k(A),
> \end{align}
> thus showing that $k(A) \subset k(B)$.

And, from the last result, we can prove the following:

> Let $\mathscr{A}$ be any (non-empty) collection of subsets of $X$. Then we have
> $$
> k \left( \cap_{A \in \mathscr{A} } A \right) \subset \cap_{ A \in \mathscr{A} } k(A).
> $$

Proof:

> Let us put
> $$
> S := \cap_{A \in \mathscr{A} } A.
> $$
> Then we have $S \subset A$ for every $A \in \mathscr{A}$, which implies that $k(S) \subset k(A)$ for every $A \in \mathscr{A}$, which in turn implies that
> $$
> k(S) \subset \cap_{A \in \mathscr{A} } k(A),
> $$
> as required.

Now for the proof of our main result.

My Attempt:

> Let us define the collection $\mathscr{T}$ of subsets of $X$ as follows:
> $$
> \mathscr{T} := \big\{ U \colon U \subset X \mbox{ and } k( X \setminus U) = X \setminus U \big\}. \tag{1} 
> $$
> We show that this collection $\mathscr{T}$ is a topology on $X$.

> Since by definition of the mapping $k$, we have $k(A) \subset X$ for every subset $A$ of $X$, therefore we must have $k(X) \subset X$. And, by [K$_2$] we have $X \subset k(X)$. Thus we have $k(X) = X$. Now as $\emptyset \subset X$ and as
> $$
> k(X \setminus \emptyset) = k(X) = X = X \setminus \emptyset, 
> $$
> we can conclude that the empty set $\emptyset$ is in $\mathscr{T}$.

Am I right?

> As $X \subset X$ and as by [K$_1$] we also have
> $$
> k(X \setminus X) = k(\emptyset) = \emptyset = X \setminus X,
> $$
> so we can conclude that the set $X$ itself is also in $\mathscr{T}$.

> Now let $\mathscr{A}$ be any subcollection of $\mathscr{T}$, and let us put
> $$
> S := \cup_{A \in \mathscr{A} } A. 
> $$
> We show that this set $S$ is in our collection $\mathscr{T}$. We note that each set $A \in \mathscr{A}$ satisfies $A \subset X$ and $k(X \setminus A) = X \setminus A$. So we have $S \subset X$ and
> \begin{align} 
> k( X \setminus S) &= k \left( X \setminus \cup_{A \in \mathscr{A} } A \right) \\
> &= k \left( \cap_{A \in \mathscr{A} } (X \setminus A) \right) \\
> &\subset \cap_{A \in \mathscr{A} } k ( X \setminus A  ) \\ 
> &= \cap_{A \in \mathscr{A} } ( X \setminus A  ) \\
> &= X \setminus \cup_{A \in \mathscr{A} } A \\
> &= X \setminus S. 
> \end{align}
> Thus we have
> $$
> k ( X \setminus S) \subset X \setminus S. \tag{2} 
> $$
> For each set $A \in \mathscr{A}$, since $A \subset S$,  we have $( X \setminus A) \subset (X \setminus S)$, which implies that $k ( X \setminus A) \subset k(X \setminus S)$, which in turn implies that
> $$
> \cup_{A \in \mathscr{A} } k ( X \setminus A) \subset k(X \setminus S). \tag{3} 
> $$
> Therefore we have
> \begin{align} 
> X \setminus S &= X \setminus \cup_{A \in \mathscr{A} } A \\
> &= \cap_{A \in \mathscr{A} } (X \setminus A ) \\ 
> &\subset \cup_{A \in \mathscr{A} } (X \setminus A ) \\
> &= \cup_{A \in \mathscr{A} } k (X \setminus A ) \\ 
> &\subset k( X \setminus S ). \qquad [ \mbox{ by (3) above } ] 
> \end{align}
> Thus we have
> $$
> X \setminus S \subset k ( X \setminus S). \tag{4} 
> $$
> From (2) and (4) we obtain
> $$
> k(X \setminus S) = X \setminus S,
> $$
> thus showing that $S$ is in $\mathscr{T}$.

Am I right?

> Let $S_1 \ldots, S_n$ be any sets from $\mathscr{T}$, and let us put $S \colon= \cap_{i=1}^n S_i$. For each $i = 1, \ldots, n$, as $S_i \subset X$ and $k\left( X \setminus S_i \right) = X \setminus S_i$, so we have $S \subset X$ and
> \begin{align}
> k ( X \setminus S) &= k \left( X \setminus \cap_{i=1}^n S_i \right) \\
> &= k \left( \cup_{i=1}^n \left( X \setminus S_i \right) \right) \\
> &= \cup_{i=1}^n k \left( X \setminus S_i \right) \qquad [ \mbox{ from [K$_3$] } ]  \\
> &= \cup_{i=1}^n \left( X \setminus S_i \right) \\
> &= X \setminus \cap_{i=1}^n S_i \\
> &= X \setminus S,
> \end{align}
> thus showing that our set $S$ is in $\mathscr{T}$.

> Thus our collection $\mathscr{T}$ in (1) above is indeed a topology on $X$.

> Next, we show that, for every subset $A$ of $X$, we have $k(A) = \overline{A}$, where $\overline{A}$ denotes the $\mathscr{T}$-closure of set $A$ in $X$.

> Let $\mathscr{C}$ be the collection of all the $\mathscr{T}$-closed supersets of $A$. Then $X$ is in $\mathscr{C}$ trivially so that $\mathscr{C}$ is a non-empty collection of sets. We show that
> $$
> k(A) = \cap_{C \in \mathscr{C} } C. \tag{5} 
> $$
> We of course have
> $$ 
> A \subset \cap_{C \in \mathscr{C} } C. \tag{6} 
> $$
> For each $C \in \mathscr{C}$, as $X \setminus C$ is in $\mathscr{T}$, so we have
> $$ 
> k(C) = k\big( X \setminus (X \setminus C) \big) = X \setminus (X \setminus C) = C,
> $$
> that is,
> $$
> k(C) = C. \tag{7} 
> $$
> Therefore we have
> \begin{align} 
> k(A) &\subset k \left( \cap_{C \in \mathscr{C} } C \right) \qquad [ \mbox{ by (6) above } ] \\
> &\subset \cap_{C \in \mathscr{C} } k(C) \\
> &= \cap_{C \in \mathscr{C} } C \qquad [ \mbox{ by (7) above } ]. 
> \end{align}
> Thus we have
> $$
> k(A) \subset \cap_{C \in \mathscr{C} } C. \tag{8} 
> $$
> Morevoer, by [K$_2$] above we have $A \subset k(A)$, and since $k(A) \subset X$, we also have
> $$ \big( X \setminus k(A) \big) \subset X $$
> and
> \begin{align} 
> k \big( X \setminus \big(X \setminus k(A) \big) \big) &= k \big( k(A) \big) \\ 
> &= k(A) \\ 
> &= X \setminus \big(X \setminus k(A) \big),
> \end{align}
> which shows that $X \setminus k(A)$ is in $\mathscr{T}$, thus showing that $k(A)$ is a $\mathscr{T}$-closed superset of $A$ and hence $k(A)$ is also in $\mathscr{C}$, and therefore we have
> $$
> \cap_{C \in \mathscr{C} } C \subset k(A), 
> $$
> which together with (8) above yields (5).

Am I right?

> Finally, let $\mathscr{T}^\prime$ be any topology on $X$ such that, for each subset $A$ of $X$, the $\mathscr{T}^\prime$-closure of $A$ equals $k(A)$. We show that
> $$
> \mathscr{T}^\prime = \mathscr{T}. \tag{9} 
> $$

> Let $U$ be any set of $\mathscr{T}$. Then $U \subset X$ and $k(X \setminus U) = X \setminus U$. [Refer to (1) above.] But then sinc $(X \setminus U ) \subset X$, the $\mathscr{T}^\prime$-closure of $X \setminus U$ equals $k(X \setminus U) = X \setminus U$, thus showing that $X \setminus U$ is $\mathscr{T}^\prime$-closed, which implies that $U$ is in $\mathscr{T}^\prime$, from which it follows that
> $$
> \mathscr{T} \subset \mathscr{T}^\prime. \tag{10} 
> $$

Am I right?

> Conversely, suppose that $V$ is in $\mathscr{T}^\prime$. Then the set $X \setminus V$ is a $\mathscr{T}^\prime$-closed subset of $X$ and therefore the $\mathscr{T}^\prime$-closure of $X \setminus V$ equals $X \setminus V$, which implies that $k( X \setminus V) = X\setminus V$ by our hypothesis about $\mathscr{T}^\prime$, which in turn implies that $V \in \mathscr{T}$ and therefore we have
> $$
> \mathscr{T}^\prime \subset \mathscr{T},
> $$
> which together with (10) above  yields (9).

Am I right?

Is my proof solid enough in each and every detail? Or, are there issus therein of correctness or
clarity?

Comment: One small comment: In the sequence around (3), you can just apply K2 directly to get $X \setminus S \subseteq k(X \setminus S)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler absolutely! You're right.  Point taken! Thanks.

Comment: In case you're interested (and want more practice by proving similar results), there are several other ways of defining a unique topology on a set in terms of a (so called) topological operator and some axioms for that operator. For example, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2254363/13130).